# I can not use ggmap or any replated resource in R to plot my map

Tags: r

My code is:

```
map_1 <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -76.12335, lat = 43.03209), zoom = 10)
```

And I got this message:

```
Warning in download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
  cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.03209,-76.12335&zoom=10&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&sensor=false': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Error in download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") : 
  cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.03209,-76.12335&zoom=10&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&sensor=false'
```

Comment: HTTP status 403 means that the server does not allow you to complete the operation.

Comment: I saw lots of people have the same problem as me. They said google api is needed here. But I don't know how to like link the api key to my project.

Comment: A [recent article](https://lucidmanager.org/geocoding-with-ggmap/) explains how to obtain and link an API key.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by other users, Google changed the API you need a key, all the information is in the package [README](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap). You will need to register a token with `register_google`.